# Using Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons in CSS

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I would like to add a Twitter bootstrap glyphicon to replace the image reference in the CSS file below though not sure how.

```
.edit-button {
  background: url('../img/edit.png') no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

In HTML I would add it as follows:

```
<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
```

Any ideas?

update - tried the following though it only shows width and height in Firefox's firebug:

```
.edit-button
{
  /* background: url('../img/edit.png') no-repeat; */
  background: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png) no repeat -96px -72px !important;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

not sure why it's not being picked up ?

Comment: It works on my machine. Make sure the path is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why don't you use `<i>` tag for your edit **button**? Try this:

```
<button type="submit" name="edit" class="edit-button btn btn-primary">
   <i class="icon icon-edit icon-white"></i>
   Edit
</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Though I'd like to know if it's possible to update the CSS I included above to show the glyphicon instead of image. If it is possible I'd like to know how :)

Comment: use this `background: url(glyphicons-halflings.png) no repeat -96px -72px !important;` as it is the sprite image so that you have to specify which position the image is.

Comment: thanks for that. I made the change you suggested and in firebug it does not appear. In the browser it looks like an empty grey little box :0 ? just updated my origin post...

Comment: Hi tried again with minor update as follows: background: url('../img/glyphicons-halflings.png') no-repeat -96px -72px !important; just had to add single quotes around image name and hyphen in 'no-repeat'. +1 for your help and fast response :)

Comment: Good alternate suggestion, but doesn't answer the question. My clickable object is a table header and I don't want to append an icon in there and change it out when I need the image to change.

Comment: -1 Edit/fix the answer to answer the OP question. He asked how to add the icon through css. I see the comments, but most people dont read the comments.

Comment: The poster asked how to do this with CSS. You completely missed the point. And I'm not trying to be negative, but how did your answer get marked as the correct one?

Answer (score 109):

I like using the :after or :before method...

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://glyphicons.com/" class="arrow">Click Here</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow:after {
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e080";
}
```

This should work assuming you have the glyphicon fonts (they come free with Bootstrap)

Comment: To get the character code you can open up the Bootstrap docs with the glyphicons in your browser and inspect it with developer tools.

Comment: Here's a [cheatsheet](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/#) with all Glyphicon entities (for the `content: ""` part):

Comment: On the above cheatsheet page you can go to the console and run this: `$('span[data-unicode]').each(function(k,v){ console.log( k + ' ' + $(v).attr('class') + ' ' + $(v).data('unicode') ) });` to get a list of glyph names and its entity